# How to copy the rows of a table column to another table column

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I want to copy multiple rows from the table exam_sections and insert it to exam_students.But im confused on how do i gonna get it working. Im having an error in the WHERE clause. Anybody can help me? btw, Sorry for my bad english.

heres is my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['Add'])){
    session_start();
    $year = $_POST['year'];
    $course = $_POST['course'];
    $block = $_POST['block'];
    $examinergroupid = $_SESSION['usergroupid'];
    $subject_id = $_SESSION['subject_id'];

    $add = mysql_query("
INSERT INTO 
exam_students (stud_valid_nos, stud_email, stud_subject_id, stud_group_id )
SELECT 
exam_sections.sec_id_num,
exam_sections.sec_email, 
'$subject_id','$examinergroupid'  
WHERE exam_sections.sec_year = '$year'
AND exam_sections.sec_course = '$course'
AND exam_sections.sec_block = '$block'")
or die(mysql_error());


    }
```

Comment: There is no FROM table name in your SELECT query

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
INSERT INTO 
    exam_students (stud_valid_nos, stud_email, stud_subject_id, stud_group_id )
SELECT 
    sec_id_num,
    sec_email, 
    '$subject_id',
    '$examinergroupid'
FROM exam_sections
WHERE sec_year = '$year'
    AND sec_course = '$course'
    AND sec_block = '$block'
```